# Answers count in "Deleted Recent Questions" page taking into account deleted answers I can't see

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, deleted-posts-pages

Recently deleted questions page answer counter shows the number of all answers, including deleted, which are not visible to normal users. On my page it says 2, but I only see 1, and I know there was one other that the poster must have deleted himself.

Is this by design or..?

**UPD**: so I just undeleted the question to see what will be the answer count for me, at least. It was 1. Then I re-deleted it and the answer count became 2 again.

Here's a nice picture of:

- The question in the list of all my questions (undeleted),
- The recently deleted questions page,
- The deleted question's page itself

[image]

Comment: Yep, most likely a bug. Can you post link to such a question page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/1306322 but I don't know if you can see them

Comment: also the question with 1 deleted and 1 visible answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300334/rounding-to-the-nearest-whole-number

Comment: Can't see your list but can see that question you deleted. There is indeed one answer deleted by its author after getting two downvotes. Can you please undelete the question just to check what is the answer count then delete again?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd done, see the question update.

Comment: Thanks, this confirm beyond doubt we're dealing with a bug. If you can add screenshots of both states it would be super. LOL, you read my mind, you added as I was typing! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I was just shopping up a screenshot.

Comment: Wait... but if you're in the question page itself, what is the count?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd updated screenshot! It was 1. So the number is "incorrect" only on the page that lists recently deleted questions.

Comment: I got confused, thought you mean the count in the question page itself. Updated the title and tags now to reflect the actual bug better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleted question answer counts are kind of a weird beast, since the assumption before now has been "if you can see a deleted question, you can see it's answers" that's the number we store and display.

As it is impractical to calculate the "number you will see when you click this"-answer-count for a list of deleted questions, the intended behavior here is to "show the link as if the question / answer were undeleted".

Comment: Well, if the site can properly calc me the number of answers I actually see on the question's page, why can't it do the same on the deleted questions page? Basically it only takes to figure out whether a user has privileges to see deleted answers, and (the easy way) get the same number user would get on the question's page and put it on the deleted questions page. I bet it's not too hard to implement.

Comment: @user1306322 Our count normalization gets tossed around a bit once a post is deleted is the problem, with undeleted stuff there's no query to figure out whether a user can "see" something most of the time.  That wouldn't be the case here, and most of indexes are optimized around undeleted things.  It's very nearly "no queries" vs. "many, rather slow, queries" (there are some edge cases naturally).

Comment: Oh, so it would impact performance then. Okay, that's reasonable.